# Intel GPU compute only mode?

Tags: linux, opencl, gpu, intel, gpgpu

I was wondering if it is possible to force the Intel GPU to be in a "OpenCL-only" mode in a Linux environment, only making OpenCL work.

We already have disabled X server and graphical software, but we would like to completly disable "video work" on this card.

Comment: did you try removing intel drivers and installing amd app sdk for opencl dll? Amd app sdk binaries were said to be able to see other brands devices you should try that.

Comment: @huseyintugrulbuyukisik: This is a Linux question.  You mentioned DLLs, and the rest of it sounds Windowsy, so I don't think that applies.  Updated tags to make that more obvious.

Comment: Thanks for the update. You're right, it's a Linux-only problematic. I'm trying to limit the consumption of my mini-ITX board by removing any useless things who would consume some power (like the graphics core).

Comment: Here is linux pack http://developer.amd.com/tools-and-sdks/opencl-zone/amd-accelerated-parallel-processing-app-sdk/ in linux it is not dll ofcourse it is something like .so file